# How to resolve "Could not find goal '' in plugin io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.6.1."?

Tags: java, quarkus

I am new to quarkus and unable to understand why this error pops up and how can I resolve it. Do i need to make pom.xml changes?

This is the error I get for build failure when trying to run my quarkus application.

[ERROR] Could not find goal '' in plugin io.quarkus:quarkus-maven-plugin:2.6.1.Final among available goals add-extension, add-extensions, analyze-call-tree, build, check-for-updates, create, create-extension, create-extension-legacy, create-jbang, dependency-tree, dev, generate-code, generate-code-tests, go-offline, help, list-categories, list-extensions, list-platforms, prepare, prepare-tests, remote-dev, remove-extension, remove-extensions, test -> [Help 1]

Comment: `Could not find goal '' in plugin` tells you that you've configured an empty / no goal to be executed. The list that follows is the set of known goals for that plugin. Can you show the relevant part of your `pom.xml` on how you've configured this plugin execution? Or perhaps the general quarkus configuration if the plugin definition is inherited.

Comment: I would suggest generating an application from `code.quarkus.io` as it will shield you from such details

Comment: <quarkus.version>2.6.1.Final</quarkus.version>
 <dependency>
                <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
                <artifactId>quarkus-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.